# How do I pass --homedir to git when signing using GPG?

Tags: linux, git, gnupg

I have a custom location where I have my GPG keys, which is different from the default `~/.gnupg` directory.

I need to sign a git commit using GPG, but I can't find any option to specify the custom location to Git: it always searches in the default one.

Is there an option for this? I tried modifying:

`program = /usr/bin/gpg --homedir ~/.mygnupg` in the `.git/config` file but no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`GNUPGHOME` environment variable](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html#sec-2-9):

```
GNUPGHOME=~/.mygnupg git commit ...
```

You can also [set this variable in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467/12606) if you want it to always be set to that value.